# How can I validate against all special characters in the attachments file name?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, web-part, javascript

By default SharePoint does not allow the following special characters to be present in attachment file names

`~, #, %, & , *, {, }, \, :, <, >, ?, /, |, “`

How can I validate that any attachments file name does not have ANY special characters(not just the ones above, but all special characters)?

Comment: Are you fine with PowerShell code?

Comment: Powershell wont help with validation on upload. You could use it to check (and change) your files prior to uploading... Make sure to develop and test,test,test on a **copy** of your files, I once ruined a fileshare..and.. you guessed it... the backup was 2 days old

Answer (score 2):

All of the characters you list are non-word characters. They can be detected by using this Regex:

```
^\W|[^\w]
```

`^\W` means:

> Matches any string that starts with a non-word character

`[^\w]` means:

> Matches any characters that are non-word characters

Answer (score 1):

If you can deploy a visual studio solution, then you can use an Event Receiver.

I have used an array to store all the chars I want to skip/validate:

```
public static string[] invalidChars = new string[] { ";", "#", "/", "~", "#", "%", "&", "*", "{", "}", ":", "<", ">", "?", "¿", "+", "|", "^", "'", "@", "[", "]", ",", "$", "=", "!", "¡", "(", ")", "_", "\\" };
```

And then in the Event Receiver on "ItemAdding":

```
try
{
     SPList myList = __properties.Web.Lists["your list"];
     SPListItem myItem = myList.GetItemById(__properties.ListItemId.ToString());
     foreach (string myAttach in myItem.Attachments)
     {
          foreach (string invalidChar in invalidChars)
          {
               if (myAttach.Contains(invalidChar))
               {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid Character: " + invalidChar + "in filename: " + myAttach);
               }    
          }
     }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     properties.Cancel = true;
     properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
     properties.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
     throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: There's a way if you are using InfoPath to customize your form too. Just let me know. Hope to help.